# adding weekends and excluding working days

Tags: tableau-api

How can I create a calculated field in Tableau that shows me the following;

it should exclude weekdays working hours between 08:00 am-16:00pm
It should include full weekends.

Trying to find who is login to the system after working hours.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Can you please give an example of sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to flag unauthorised logins, I have done it like that-

Sample data I have used-

[image]

Calculated field `unauth_login` like this

```
DATEPART('iso-weekday', [Login_time]) >5
OR
DATEPART('hour', [Login_time])>=16 
OR
DATEPART('hour', [Login_time])<8
```

and you will your desired results with `yes` values flagged separately from `no`.  Screenshot

[image]

Do tell me whether I got you correct?
Assumption: Saturday and Sunday are weekends are in your country/locale.

Comment: you are the best. thanks a lot!!!